# Testing App Store "Distribution" version

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to test the App Store Distribution bundle that's to be submitted to iTunes Connect, on a device, e.g. iPod Touch?

Also, for the distribution bundle is it important to remove the file "Entitlemenets.plist"?

Answer (score 4):

You can run a **Distribution** build on a device with your **Ad Hoc** provisioning profile.

(You can't launch it with the debugger though.)

Also, you can submit an **Ad Hoc** build to the App Store.

This is because both **Ad Hoc** and **Distribution** builds are signed with the same distribution certificate. (There is no separate "Ad Hoc certificate".)

Do not remove Entitlements.plist. It must be present.

Comment: What do you mean by "both Ad Hoc and Distribution builds are signed with the same distribution certificate"?  The Provisioning Portal has a field to indicate whether a distribution cert is for the App Store or Ad Hoc distribution method.  That sounds like one needs 2 separate cert hence 2 separate profiles.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting this -- my ad hoc and distribution builds are certainly signed with different certificates.

Comment: No, they use the same certificate. You can only create 1 distribution certificate for your developer account on the provistioning portal. Your ad hoc and distribution builds do use different provisioning profiles yes - but they use the same certificate - the distribution certificate. So Jon-Eric is right.

Comment: @Jon-Eric. I'm confused by the terminology being used here. Isn't an Ad-Hoc build a type of distribution build, of where there are a few different types? (In Xcode, after creating an archive, if you choose ad-hoc it says "Sign and package for Ad-hoc distribution". Therefore I'm confused by what is meant here by the term distribution build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. All you have to do is first install your app with the Ad Hoc provisioning profile on your device. Then, when you have removed your app again, you can install it with a build signed with your App Store provisioning profile.

This works because when you install the Ad Hoc build, the Ad Hoc provisioning profile is installed on your phone, which adds your distribution certificate, which is the same used by the App Store provisioning profile. This is sufficient for your distribution build to run.

The provisioning profile is merely a set of rules explaining which devices are allowed to install your certificate. The Ad Hoc profile allows your registered devices to install your distribution certificate. The App Store profile allows App Store users to install it. Once the device has the certificate, they do not need to install it again and can use your app regardless of which profile is bundled in the app.

> Step by step for Xcode to test your distribution bundle:
>
> **(Note: this does NOT require a jailbroken phone)**
>
> First time you want to test your app with a distribution build:
>
> 1. Create provisioning profiles for app store and ad hoc in provisioning portal and install them on your mac.
> 2. Archive your project
> 3. Press distribute and choose ad hoc / enterprise
> 4. Choose the ad hoc provisiong profile
> 5. Install the package on your iPhone (via iTunes or whatever way you prefer). Verify that the Ad Hoc profile is installed in your phone
>      settings
> 6. Remove app, but keep the installed profile on your phone
>
> Now, every time you want to release your app and pre-test it with your
>   release build, you can do this:
>
> 1. Archive your project
> 2. Press distribute and choose ad hoc / enterprise
> 3. Choose the **App Store** provisioning profile
> 4. Install on your phone and test it (using iTunes, for example)
> 5. Upload the exported .ipa to App Store (via Application Loader)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the equivalent of the App Store distribution bundle by creating a target identical to the App Store target except signed with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, you can actually test a distribution build :

http://nikhilkerala.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-test-app-store-distribution.html

Comment: In case that link disappears, the suggested solution is "jailbreak your phone."