# iOS Developer and Distribution certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to iOS development and developing my project with APNs support. I used both Developer and Distribution certificate in my project its working fine.

While changing my certificate that I need some configuration in my server from **APNs_sandbox** to **APNs_live** API because **APNs_sandbox** work only in Developer Certificate as we known.

**My Question:**

Q1) Is it possible to install my app using Distribution certificate without using test flight and with my cable.

Q2) How could I solve this problem.

Comment: Q1) Yes, you can just build your app (as a .ipa) and install it using iTunes.  Q2) What problem?

Comment: Thank you response. While using my distribution certificate I can't get Xcode compiler error log.

Comment: Did you do Product/Archive not Product/Build?

Comment: I Archive my project then submit to the testflight.

Comment: I though your previous comment meant you got an error when building. But now I see that's not what you mean. But I have no idea what you do mean. What does "I can't get Xcode compiler error log" mean? What do you mean by compiler error log and why do you want to get it?

Comment: K fine, I need my project compiler to log, Compile logs only generated while we run our project on simulator else directly run on device use our developer certificate. So I need a solution to get compiler log in Distribution certificate. Note: Compile logs not mean as error else crash error.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean A compile log is generated when you compile your project to record compilation errors, nothing to do with running a project. If you got compilation errors then your project can't build therefore it can't run. So you are using the term compile logs incorrectly and you must be referring to some other type of log.  If you want logging in your code that is easy to add. I think you should start a new question, this one has gone completely off topic from your original question.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble,I am new to iOS development, I mean ex: NSLog("checking") then log will be generate on Xcode Debug area.

Comment: If your iPhone is connected to your Mac, you can see some real time output by going to Xcode | Organizer | Devices. For persistent logging I personally use CocoaLumberjack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82996/discussion-between-manikandan-d-and-svetlana-slutstokyovich).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres no way to test your app directly into your device with the distribution certificate, you need to use testflight or generate an adhoc distribution and install your app in an adhoc way only to test the push notifications.

Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16731963/3290977) to get more info about adhoc testing/distributon.

Hope it helps.