# Problems with installing AppStore distribution build on device with AdHoc profile

Tags: ios, build

I have problem with installing Appstore distribution build/release into my iphone.

After reading the post [Testing App Store "Distribution" version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841136/testing-app-store-distribution-version) and [How to test the final distribution build before submitting it for review to the iPhone app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076149/how-to-test-the-final-distribution-build-before-submitting-it-for-review-to-the)

I know that it is possible to install Appstore distribution build into iphone/device after installing AdHoc provisioning profile (see the posts I read). However, I couldn't do it and i dont know why.

Here is a list of what I have done:

1. Created AppID from developer portal.
2. Added the device.
3. Created certificate.
4. Created Adhoc provisioning profile with the device.
5. Created AppStore provisioning profile with the same certificate.
6. Installed both profiles and certificate into build machine.
7. Build the AdHoc release.
8. Installed the Adhoc profile to device.
9. Test the Adhoc build. The app works on device.
10. Remove the app from device.
11. Build the AppStore release with AppStore profile.
12. Install the app to device and error.

`Error message: "Unable to Download Application".`

If I drag and drop it from xcode, it will give me the following errors: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.
0xE8008016

Any idea how i can resolve it?

Thank you. B.

Comment: I had the same problem. You need to check it out [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21058295

Answer (score 1):

If you created build with distribution certificate (   AppStore release )  then you can not install it on device from any tools.  You should upload this build to appstore and install if from appstore( after it approved from apple)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what Apple said, but according to my old project and the link i attached in my post, it is possible. Currently, with my old project, I can install Appstore distribution build on provisioned devices that have Adhoc distribution profile installed. (See the link I attached). I just do not know how to set it up since this is set up by someone else.